# What is the difference between Django syntax

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-3.0

hello guys what the difference between this two syntax

'blog' and 'blog.apps.BlogConfig'

in project this is located in installed app.

I think both are same but there should be difference between this 2 commands because they looks like different

first one is this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

seccond one is :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

Comment: Read the docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/

Comment: yes I will my friend but there is the only definition of apps.config and I will read The docs but I want before reading the docs get information about this 2 syntax and what's the difference between both them

Comment: TLDR: Just referencing the app will load the app in the "default" way, using a config can potentially run some code before/after the app is loaded to perform some customisation or just set some variables that change the name of the app (useful for customising the admin)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a custom configuration(`BlogConfig`) for your app.

You have at least two options to register the app with custom config in project settings(`INSTALLED_APPS`).

1. (if)You have a variable `default_app_config = 'blog.apps.BlogConfig'` in `blog/__init__.py` file, then inserting `blog` into `INSTALLED_APPS` will be the same as `blog.apps.BlogConfig`. If you don't have it in `__init__.py`, `BlogConfig` won't be applied in the example below.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'blog',
     ...,
]
```

2. (if)You have an empty `__init__.py` in your app. Then to apply the custom config you must include the path to config.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
     ...,
]
```

putting only `blog` in the second example will work without the custom config.

Comment: thanks, Davit you help me a lot. because I'm a beginner Django programmer and for me, that kind of tips is very helpful

Comment: Glad that helped you. If you that the answer is correct then please accept it.